# Jenkins jobs on slave servers

Tags: jenkins

I have many Jenkins Jobs that I need to run on every Build,

At present time I have 4 slave servers.

I would like the jobs to run in parallel as much as possible, hence I defined the jobs as follow:

1. Execute concurrent builds if necessary - Disabled
2. Restrict where this project can be run - Enabled with the following values SalveLinux1HT||SalveLinux2HT||SalveLinux3HT||SalveLinux4HT

To my understanding if Job A and B are triggered at the same time, one should use 1HT and the other should use 2HT and they can run in parallel

however Jenkins build job A on all 4 slaves and only after it's finished he will build job B on all 4 slaves

This is the opposite of my goal

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

- [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

You can find both installation and configuration instructions of this plugin at the above mentioned link.

If you want to run any jobs in parallel you can use following scripts:

```
   parallel (
    // job A and B will be scheduled in parallel.
    { build("jobA") },
    { build("jobB") }
)
// jobC will be triggered after jobs A and B are  completed
build("jobC")
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you!
I'm already using MultiJob plugin, should I replace it or just use build flow as an extra plugin?

Comment: You can use either of the approach, use it as a extra plugin it should not be that much overhead for Jenkins

Comment: Please don't hesitate to mark the question as answered, if the above has helped :)